# Selenium + Python Data Scraping not working. the product name of Shopee are not saving in the csv file

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

My Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
import csv
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://shopee.ph/search?keyword=arduino&noCorrection=true&page=0&withDiscount=true")
sleep(2)

SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 0.5
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

while True:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height
Categories = []
Categories.append(["NAME"])
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div')
for item in items:
    Name = item.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@class="fBhek2 _2xt0JJ"]/div[2]/div/div').text
    print(Name)
    Categories.append(Name)
    sleep(1)
with open('Shopee.csv', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    Import = csv.writer(file,lineterminator='\n')
    Import.writerows(Categories)
```

so im trying to data scrape the Shopee using Selenium and Pycharm. first is the product name is appearing in the Run Console but after 19 product..it causing error(you can see in the picture). 2nd, even if the product are appearing on Rune Console. NONE of them are being stored inside. here is the link of the Shopee i want to data scrape: https://shopee.ph/search?keyword=arduino&noCorrection=true&page=0&withDiscount=true

i wonder what is wrong? why none of them are being stored inside. then for every 19 product name display, it causing error(i also tried this on different product search such as laptop, etc).

[Screenshot of CSV File with no inputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmICh.png)

Comment: error 404 not output error found, This community is not used to debug code

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should improve your locators.
Try this:

```
items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="col-xs-2-4 shopee-search-item-result__item"]')
Name = item.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@data-sqe="name"]').text
```

Also I see you first scrolling till the page bottom with

```
while True:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height
```

and only after that you trying to get the products data with

```
items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div')
for item in items:
    Name = item.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@class="fBhek2 _2xt0JJ"]/div[2]/div/div').text
    print(Name)
    Categories.append(Name)
    sleep(1)
```

while you should get the products data inside the scrolling, otherwise you will get only the products presented on the lower part of the screen